# How to fix the Thread 1: SIGABRT error (with console)

Tags: ios, multithreading, sigabrt

I have a problem. I am making a very simple app in Objective C and Xcode keeps giving me an error that says Thread 1: SIGABRT. This is what the console says:

> 2013-12-27 20:01:24.375 RMF[1568:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Main_menu_rmf.'

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0174e5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bd8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017de6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0117e9ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x010eacfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x010ea253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x0114c70a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x004cda15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014cf7d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x01749b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x004cc56e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x0033e605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    12  UIKit                               0x0033edad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    13  UIKit                               0x0033f0ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    14  UIKit                               0x0033f5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    15  UIKit                               0x002679fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    16  UIKit                               0x00267d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    17  UIKit                               0x0026802d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    18  UIKit                               0x0027289a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    19  UIKit                               0x00225cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    20  UIKit                               0x0022a3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    21  UIKit                               0x0023e87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    22  UIKit                               0x0023ede9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    23  UIKit                               0x0022c025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x036912f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x03690e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x016c9d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x016c9a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x016f477c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x016f3ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x016f38db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    31  UIKit                               0x00229add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    32  UIKit                               0x0022bd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    33  RMF                                 0x00002c7d main + 141
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d76725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please provide more details.

Comment: Check duplicate question - you need to fix you outlets in IB